# Change event not works on select

Tags: jquery

I tried to bind on `change` event to the select tag with few options. If I'm binds it to `select` tag it's not works. If I bind on `click` event to `H1` tag and it's works ok.

html

```
<div class="subtitle_block">
  <span>Резюме по разделам</span>
    <form name='region_filter' action='/jobseek/search_cv/' method='post'>                                                
      <select id="id_region" class="" name="region">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Все</option>
        <option value="3">Донецк</option>
        <option value="2">Киев</option>
        <option value="1">Харьков</option>
      </select>                    
    </form>
  <div class="clear_both"></div>
</div>
```

I tried like that

```
$(function(){
    console.log($('#id_region')); //this is works
    $('#id_region').bind('change', function(){console.log('asdf')}); //this is not works
});
```

And like that

```
$(function(){
console.log($('#id_region')); //this is works
$('#id_region').change(function(){console.log('asdf')}); //this is not works
});
```

Even like that

```
$(function(){
console.log($('#id_region')); //this is works
$('#id_region').click(function(){console.log('asdf')}); //this is not works
});
```

What is wrong in there?

Comment: uhmm i put your code in jsfiddle and it works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting your code inside `$(document).ready()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log($('#id_region')); //this is works
  $('#id_region').change(function(){console.log('asdf')}); //this is not works
});
```

See [this working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4YsYp/)

Comment: jsfiddle are Cool thing, thanks!!! Your advices is very useful, but my code does not work. Perhaps the problem with the template is more complicated than described here.

Comment: Isn't $(function(){}) just an alias for $(document).ready(function(){})?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<body>
        <div class="subtitle_block">
          <span>Резюме по разделам</span>
            <form name='region_filter' action='/jobseek/search_cv/' method='post'>                                                
              <select id="id_region" class="" name="region">
                <option value="" selected="selected">Все</option>
                <option value="3">Донецк</option>
                <option value="2">Киев</option>
                <option value="1">Харьков</option>
              </select>                    
            </form>
          <div class="clear_both"></div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('#id_region').bind("change", null, function() {
                alert('event fired');
            });
        });
        </script>
    </body>
```